# Weighted Union Find

Tags: induction, computational-complexity

Prove that the weighted union (w_union) takes O(log2(n)) for FIND in the worst case on a graph which has n nodes by proving by induction.

I'm not sure how I would prove this at all, I know how I would prove recurrences but this has stumped me and I'm not sure how I would do this or even get started at all.

If someone can help me out with this, that would be great.

Thanks guys.

code:

public void w_union(int u, int v)
   {
       int pu, pv, nu, nv;

```
   pu= c_find(u);
   pv= c_find(v);

   if (pu == pv) return;

   nu= -1 * parent[pu]; /* nu = # nodes in component with u. */
   nv= -1 * parent[pv]; /* nv = # nodes in component with v. */

   if (nu <  nv)
   { /* pv is the new root. */
      parent[pv]+= parent[pu]; /* Update # nodes. */
      parent[pu]= pv;
   }
   else
   { /* pu is the new root. */
      parent[pu]+= parent[pv]; /* Update # nodes. */
      parent[pv]= pu;
   }
```

}

```
    int c_find(int u)
   {   int v, top;
        top=0;
        while (parent[u] >= 0)
        {
           stack[top]= u; top++;
           u=parent[u];
        }
        while (top > 0)
        {
            top--; v= stack[top]; 
            parent[v]=u;
        }
        return(u);
   }
```

Comment: If you are asking us to consider time complexity of an algorithm... well, it might pay to tell us the algorithm.  Also, it is considered good practice here to include all of your work so far (worthwhile or otherwise) so that we know where you're at and how we can help you along.

Comment: Hi Nicholas, thanks for your reply. Sorry, I forgot to add that, it has been added now. This is just a practice question for an upcoming exam so I am trying to figure out how to prove it. Thanks again my friend!

Answer (score 1):

FIND just goes up and down the tree, so the complexity of FIND is $O(\textrm{maximum possible tree height for }n\textrm{ nodes})$. Therefore all you have to show is that a weighted-union-find tree with $n$ nodes has height $O(\log_2 n)$.

Let $H(n)$ be the height of the tallest possible w-u-f tree with $n$ nodes. Clearly $H(1)=0$.

Any w-u-f tree of $n>1$ nodes resulted from merging a w-u-f tree with $n_1$ nodes and one with $n_2\le n_1$ nodes. The resulting tree of $n=n_1+n_2$ nodes has height at most $\min(H(n_1),H(n_2)+1)$, because when merging, weighted union-find always puts a tree with fewer nodes below the root of the other tree. Then, because $n_2\le\frac{n}{2}$, we see that $H(n)\le H(\frac{n}{2})+1$, and therefore $H(n)\le \log_2  n =O(\log_2 n)$ as needed.

Comment: I think it might be $\max(H(n_1), H(n_2) + 1)$